# install MPICH in ubuntu singularity container

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install MPICH within my singularity container, but when I run the following code  I get an error  saying it cannot locate  mpich2:

```
apt-get --yes update
apt-get  --yes  upgrade
apt-get install --yes build-essential 
apt-get install mpich2
```

Any ideas?

I then tried building version mpich-3.2 from source but I keep getting an error that my automake version is incorrect. What line should I add to install the correct version 1.15 or higher?

Answer (score 4):

Of the currently supported Ubuntu releases, `mpich2` is available only in 14.04 as a [transitional dummy package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mpich2).
As you can see on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=mpich), the package you want is called `mpich`, which is contained in the `universe` sources. The sources of 14.04 have v3.0, 16.04 to 17.04 v3.2, 17.10 and 18.04 come with v3.3.

Make sure you have the `universe` sources enabled andrun these installation commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mpich
```

Comment: Hello,Thank you. But I get the same error that it can find the package

Comment: @airzinger1 make sure that the `universe` repository is enabled in your sources and then update again

Comment: Hello,How do I enable the universe repositiory in my script?

Comment: You can do that by (carefully!) editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding `universe` to the list of components, e.g. `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe`.