# install Open MPI on HPC

Tags: software-installation, cluster

I want to install OpenMPI on a linux HPC cluster with a Slurm resource manager. I know how to build OpenMPI regulariy from source , however, how do I  install it so that it is installed properly on the  compute nodes as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just as with your [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424127/install-mpich-in-ubuntu-singularity-container) about `mpich` the answer is to install the packaged version of OpenMPI provided by your distribution on each node of your cluster.

You're running Ubuntu, so:

```
apt-get install openmpi-bin
```

The `openmpi-bin` package depends on `libopenmpi2` and `openmpi-common` so installing it will cause them to be automatically installed.

You may also want to install the documentation (`openmpi-doc`) and/or the develoment headers and libs (`libopenmpi-dev`) on another machine (perhaps on the head node of your cluster) - these aren't needed on the computation nodes.

---

BTW, If you have, e.g., `pdsh` installed and configured on your head node, you could install `openmpi-bin` on your entire cluster with one command.  e.g.

```
pdsh -g all 'apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openmpi-bin'
```

FYI, `pdsh` ("Parallel Distributed Shell") was written by [LLNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Livermore_National_Laboratory) (who were also the authors of `slurm`) in order to help automate administration and management of their clusters.  It was written to be an enhanced open-source clone of an IBM program called `dsh` ("Distributed Shell")

---

Also BTW, you can find a list of Ubuntu openmpi packages AND packages that use OpenMPI at: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openmpi

The list includes the versions of the packages available for each Ubuntu release.